# How Do I Add/Update Website and Notes on Live Contact?

Tags: sdk, live, onedrive

Does anyone know the correct field names to update the Notes and Website fields when using the Live SDK (or even REST)?

I'm able to create a contact easily via liveClient.PostAsync("me/contacts", contact) where I have populated the Dictionary of keys/values for most things, but can't seem to populate Notes or Website.

(Of course I am also unable to ever see these fields for a contact via the returned response, but that's secondary.)

Here's an example of what DOESN'T work: contact.Add("website", "http://www.msdn.com");

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Notes and Website contact fields aren't supported through the Live SDK or REST API.